Forcing a 1:1 matching between Errors defined in a lib and Counters defined in the consumer
I have a lib that defines some categories of errors for certain functions. For example:
var (
    ErrNotFound         = errors.New("not found")
    ErrFailedParsing    = errors.New("failed parsing")
    ErrFailedProcessing = errors.New("failed processing")
)

func Run() error {
    if 1 != 2 {
        return ErrNotFound
    }

    return nil
}

The caller of this lib has a set of Counters (to be exported as metrics) for those categories of errors.
For example:
var (
    NotFoundCounter         int
    FailedParsingCounter    int
    FailedProcessingCounter int
)

func main() {
    err := Run()
    if err != nil {
        switch err {
        case ErrNotFound:
            NotFoundCounter += 1
        case ErrFailedParsing:
            FailedParsingCounter += 1
        case ErrFailedProcessing:
            FailedProcessingCounter += 1
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("counters: %d %d %d\n", NotFoundCounter, FailedParsingCounter, FailedProcessingCounter)
}

This works, but it's brittle.
If the lib is changed to add a new category of errors ErrServiceUnavailable, it will be ignored by the counter (or, at best, will default to an uncategorized error at runtime).
I'd like mechanism that allows me force a 1:1 correspondence between the lib errors and the counters during build time (e.g. in Rust I could enforce exhaustive switch/case).
I'm pretty sure I can find a solution using one of:

Reflection (e.g. on unit tests)
Changing the library to register metrics
go vet

But I'd call all of those workarounds.
Is there a better way? I suppose what I'm trying to do is quite common.

If you have a category of errors, it would be beneficial to have them all belong to the same type (Go Playground):
type MyError int

const (
    ErrNotFound MyError = iota
    ErrFailedParsing
    ErrFailedProcessing
)

func (e MyError) Error() string {
    switch e {
    case ErrNotFound:
        return "not found"

    case ErrFailedParsing:
        return "failed parsing"

    case ErrFailedProcessing:
        return "failed processing"

    default:
        return fmt.Sprintf("unknown %d", e)
    }
}

Then you could do a switch on them, handling wrapped and other errors:
        var e MyError
        if errors.As(err, &e) {
            switch e {
            case ErrNotFound:
                NotFoundCounter++

            case ErrFailedParsing:
                FailedParsingCounter++

            case ErrFailedProcessing:
                FailedProcessingCounter++
            }
        } else {
            // handle other errors
        }

That the switch is exhaustive can be checked with the exhaustive linter, which is available stand-alone or as part of golangci-lint.
As an alternative, you could publish a handler from the package you'll define the errors in:
func (e MyError) Handle(handleNotFound, handleFailedParsing, handleFailedProcessing func()) {
    switch e {
    case ErrNotFound:
        handleNotFound()

    case ErrFailedParsing:
        handleFailedParsing()

    case ErrFailedProcessing:
        handleFailedProcessing()
    }
}

And then handle the error:
        var e MyError
        if errors.As(err, &e) {
            e.Handle(
                func() { NotFoundCounter++ },
                func() { FailedParsingCounter++ },
                func() { FailedProcessingCounter++ },
            )
        } else {
            // handle other errors
        }

With this you break compatibility every time a new error is introduced and force dependent packages to adapt to the changed signature, which seems to be what you want.
